# Do I need to provide a deobfuscation file if I disabled minifyEnabled

Tags: android, kotlin, obfuscation, google-play-console, android-r8

In my app level build.gradle file I have `minifyEnabled = false` and so I believe the app will not be obfuscated.

When I go into play console to release the app, Play console says `'We recommend uploading a deobfuscation file so that your crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved'`. Is this just a warning in case I did obfuscate the application?

If I certainly do need to provide something then I am lost as I dont even see any mapping files produced when minifyEnabled is set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a warning. Even if you uploaded an obfuscated app without a deobfuscation file, you could still deobfuscate manually if you keep the file after compiling, although then Google Play can’t aggregate errors that are common between different versions of your app.  It’s not recommended to upload an app that hasn’t been minified though because of the download size.